# VB.NET remove found string with all the text between two symbols

Tags: regex, vb.net, xpath

I am looking for solution to remove some part of text between two symbols with specific word for example:

List with my words:

```
Anny
Thomas
Andreas
```

Full text to filter:

```
<name list>
<name id="bla bla bla"
anny is very good girl
</name>

<name id="jark"/>

<name id="Thomas"
specific style
</name>

<name id="andreas" 30/>

<name id="ehl"
very nice
</name>
</name list>
```

In this example I would like to be removed text containing my words, but they are also between `<name` and `</name>` or `<name` and `/>` symbols, so output will be:

```
<name id="jark"asdasdasdasd/>
```

And here is the code I came to:

```
Dim todelete() As String = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Temp\todelete.txt")
Dim doc As XDocument = XDocument.Load("C:\Temp\test.txt")
For Each badname As String in todelete
    Dim e As XElement = From element
    In doc.Elements("name list").Elements("name")
    Where element.Attribute("name").Value = badname
    Select element

e.Remove()
doc.Save()
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

If this is XML, you should use a DOM-modifying tool to do it.
If you use string manipulation, your code is susceptible to all kinds of problems if the structure of your file ever needs to be more complex.

In standard VB you could add a reference to MSXML in your project. You can then use `DOMDocument.Load(filename)`. Alternatively in .NET, use `System.Xml.XmlDocument`.

You can search for nodes using `SelectNodes` (see [XPath syntax](http://www.w3schools.com/xpath/xpath_syntax.asp))

The .net class has a `RemoveChild` method, which can be used to alter the XML without worrying about damaging the structure. Just iterate through the selected nodes and use 
   `ParentNode.RemoveChild(item)`.

Comment: Sanay i like your way of solution, check  my last add code I came to.

Comment: Does anyone have any more advice to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

## Description

`(?:<name\b)(?:\s)(?![^<\/]*?(?:Anny|Thomas|Andreas))[^<\/]*?(?:<\/name|\/)>` matches values which do not contain your sample names.

[image]

The dotted box shows the group which the innertext must not contain.

In the text you're said the open tag sets would be either `<name ... />` or `<name .... </name>` incase they are something like `<name> .... </name>` then this block `(?:\s) can be changed to`(?:\s|>)`

## Example in vb.net

```
Imports System.Text.RegularExpressions
Module Module1
  Sub Main()
    Dim sourcestring as String = "replace with your source string"
    Dim re As Regex = New Regex("(?:<name\b)(?:\s)(?![^<\/]*?(?:Anny|Thomas|Andreas))[^<\/]*?(?:<\/name|\/)>",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase OR RegexOptions.Multiline OR RegexOptions.Singleline)
    Dim mc as MatchCollection = re.Matches(sourcestring)
    Dim mIdx as Integer = 0
    For each m as Match in mc
      For groupIdx As Integer = 0 To m.Groups.Count - 1
        Console.WriteLine("[{0}][{1}] = {2}", mIdx, re.GetGroupNames(groupIdx), m.Groups(groupIdx).Value)
      Next
      mIdx=mIdx+1
    Next
  End Sub
End Module

$matches Array:
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => <name jark/>
            [1] => <name ehl
very nice
</name>
        )

)
```